# Pages Copy and Paste Horizontal/Vertical Ruler Guides

Tags: macos, pages, formatting

Is it possible to copy and paste guides on a Pages 5 document? If so, how?

Comment: Guides?  Can you clarify?

Comment: Sorry. Guides as in the lines that you drag down from the ruler to help arrange the document. E.g. Horizontal/vertical (ruler) guides. I've done the guides for one page but would like to have it for all my pages. The thought of having to manually drag down guides on every single page is very unappealing.